# R: What is a fast way to remove dominated rows from a table?

Tags: r, dplyr, multidplyr

I'm looking for a fast way to remove all dominated rows from a table (preferably using parallel processing, to take advantage of multiple cores).

By "dominated row", I mean a row that is less than or equal to another row in all columns. For example, in the following table:

```
tribble(~a, ~b, ~c,
        10,  5,  3,
        10,  4,  2,
         1,  4,  1,
         7,  3,  6)
```

Rows 2 and 3 are dominated rows (in this case they are both dominated by row 1), and should be removed. Rows 1 and 4 are not dominated by any other row and should be preserved, resulting in this table:

```
tribble(~a, ~b, ~c,
        10,  5,  3,
         7,  3,  6)
```

To further illustrate, here is the kind of code I'm looking to speed up:

```
table1 = as_tibble(replicate(3, runif(500000)))
colnames(table1) = c("a", "b", "c")
table2 = table1
for (i in 1:nrow(table1)) {
  table2 = filter(table2,
    (a > table1[i,]$a | b > table1[i,]$b | c > table1[i,]$c) |
    (a == table1[i,]$a & b == table1[i,]$b & c == table1[i,]$c) )
}
filtered_table = table2
```

I have some ideas, but figured I'd ask if there might be well-known packages/functions that do this.

---

UPDATE: Here is a fairly simple parallelization of the above code, which nevertheless provides a solid performance boost:

```
remove_dominated = function(table) {
  ncores = detectCores()
  registerDoParallel(makeCluster(ncores))
  # Divide the table into parts and remove dominated rows from each part
  tfref = foreach(part=splitIndices(nrow(table), ncores), .combine=rbind) %dopar% {
    tpref = table[part[[1]]:part[[length(part)]],]
    tp = tpref
    for (i in 1:nrow(tpref)) {
      tp = filter(tp,
                (a > tpref[i,]$a | b > tpref[i,]$b | c > tpref[i,]$c |
                (a == tpref[i,]$b & b == tpref[i,]$b & c == tpref[i,]$c) )
    }
    tp
  }
  # After the simplified parts have been concatenated, run a final pass to remove dominated rows from the full table
  t = tfref
  for (i in 1:nrow(tfref)) {
    t = filter(t,
            (a > tfref[i,]$a | b > tfref[i,]$b | c > tfref[i,]$c |
            (a == tfref[i,]$a & b == tfref[i,]$b & c == tfref[i,]$c) )
  }
  return(t)
}
```

Comment: Please define "dominated row" in words - is it a row that is strictly less than another row in all columns?

Comment: By "dominated row", I mean a row that is less than or equal to another row in all columns. For example, if row 1 has columns A=10 B=5 C=3, row 2 has A=10 B=4 C=2, and row 3 has A=1 B=4 C=1, rows 2 and 3 are dominated by row 1. I want rows 2 and 3 to be removed.

Comment: There are no duplicate rows in my particular data set, but if there were, duplicate rows should be collapsed into a single row.

Comment: (1) *"For example, if row 1 has columns A=10 B=5 C=3, row 2 has A=10 B=4 C=2, and row 3 has A=1 B=4 C=1, rows 2 and 3 are dominated by row 1. I want rows 2 and 3 to be removed."* Huh? By that logic you would end up with exactly one row -- the one with the highest values across all columns. (2) Also: How would you deal with `A=10 B=5 C=3` and `A=5 B=10 C=3`? Which one is higher?

Comment: @Maurits You gave your own counter-example, in your example (2) you wouldn't remove either.

Comment: @Alexis Yes my first statement was somewhat rhetorical (clearly my "Huh?" didn't make that clear enough;-); I'm still waiting for a revised problem statement with a clear set of rules from OP, which unfortunately is still pending. As it stands right now, OPs question is *entirely* unclear to me. This might just be me, as you seem to have provided an answer/solution.

Comment: I have added more explanation to the question. Basically, I'm trying to weed out rows that I don't need to consider from a large table. Let's say I have a table of computers with columns for clock speed, number of cores, and RAM. I want to eliminate all computers that are obviously less capable than some other computer in the table, so that I'm only left with the computers where I need to make tradeoffs (e.g. one has a faster clock speed but another one has more cores, etc).

Answer (score 2):

EDIT2: optimized version below.

I have a feeling that you can do better than this solution,
but it is probably not so trivial.
Here I just compare each row to every other row,
I just do it in a way that memory utilization is reduced,
but execution time complexity is almost quadratic in `n`
(almost because the for-loop can terminate early)...

```
library(doParallel)

n <- 50000L
table1 <- replicate(3L, runif(n))

num_cores <- detectCores()
workers <- makeCluster(num_cores)
registerDoParallel(workers)

chunks <- splitIndices(n, num_cores)
system.time({
  is_dominated <- foreach(chunk=chunks, .combine=c, .multicombine=TRUE) %dopar% {
    # each chunk has many rows to be checked
    sapply(chunk, function(i) {
      a <- table1[i,]
      # this will check if any other row dominates row "i"
      for (j in 1L:n) {
        # no row should dominate itself
        if (i == j)
          next

        b <- table1[j,]
        if (all(b >= a))
          return(TRUE)
      }

      # no one dominates "a"
      FALSE
    })
  }
})

non_dominated <- table1[!is_dominated,]
```

I create chunks of parallel tasks so that each parallel worker has to process many rows when it is called,
so that communication overhead is reduced.
I do see a considerable parallelization speed-up in my system.

EDIT: if you do have duplicated rows,
I would remove them beforehand with `unique`.

---

In this version we shuffle the indices of the rows that each worker has to process,
due to the fact that each worker has to deal with different loads for each `i`,
shuffling seems to help with load balance.

With `ordering` and `min_col_val` we can check only rows that definitely dominate row `i` in the column corresponding to `ordering`,
and `break` out of the loop once that condition is violated.
It does seem to be considerably faster in comparison.

```
ids <- sample(1L:n)
chunks <- lapply(splitIndices(n, num_cores), function(chunk_ids) {
  ids[chunk_ids]
})

system.time({
  orderings <- lapply(1L:ncol(table1), function(j) { order(table1[, j], decreasing=TRUE) })

  non_dominated <- foreach(chunk=chunks, .combine=c, .multicombine=TRUE, .inorder=FALSE) %dopar% {
    chunk_ids <- sapply(chunk, function(i) {
      a <- table1[i,]

      for (col_id in seq_along(orderings)) {
        ordering <- orderings[[col_id]]
        min_col_val <- a[col_id]

        for (j in ordering) {
          if (i == j)
            next

          b <- table1[j,]

          if (b[col_id] < min_col_val)
            break

          if (all(b >= a))
            return(FALSE)
        }
      }

      # no one dominates "a"
      TRUE
    })

    chunk[chunk_ids]
  }

  non_dominated <- table1[sort(non_dominated),]
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexis. This is along the lines of what I was thinking about as a next step, thanks for saving me time -- multidplyr isn't well suited for this, and I hadn't looked at doParallel in a while :-) Beyond that, I was thinking about dividing the table into subtables, culling dominated rows in each of the subtables in parallel, recombining the subtables into a top-level table, and repeating this divide-cull-recombine process until the top-level table was small enough (?), and then running a final cull on the top-level table. But that added complexity may or may not buy much :-)

Comment: Ok, I think I managed to make an optimized version, but can't guarantee it 100%.

Comment: Clever approach! I like how it shortcuts unnecessary comparisons.

Comment: BTW, I recently realized that [pareto optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585519/pareto-optimization-non-dominated-points) might be a better approach.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the pointer. Also -- I noticed that with my data set, the quadratic-parallel approach is actually slower than my original serial approach. Your second approach would likely be much better, but as I was thinking about it some more I came up with another idea which is relatively simple code-wise, but provides a solid performance boost. I'll append it to my question.