# locate "isolated points" in multidimensions

Tags: r, distance, knn, outliers

I have a multidimensional data set with about 10K points having 200 numeric columns. I would like to efficiently find which points are "isolated" in the sense that they are far away from the closest `n` neighbors.

For example in the set

```
{(-3, 0.5), (-2.9, 0.6), (-3.1,0.4), (-3, 2), (-2.9, 2.1), (-3.1, 2.2), (1, 0.5), (1.1, 0.6), (0.9, 0.4), (1,2) }
```

The point `(1,2)` is isolated, although its `x` and `y` values separately are not outliers.

I have tried various flavors of `kNN` in order to find the closest neighbors to each point and then deciding if these points are far (e.g. if the nth neighbor is at a distance which is an outlier to all other distances). But for `10K x 200` the fastest I got was about 40 sec. Since I have to do this many times in my code I am looking for something much faster.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at [pareto optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585519/pareto-optimization-non-dominated-points)? By itself it is not a complete solution, and it would only detect points that are isolated on the "borders" of the space, but it might be a starting point?

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look